# How to ensure external projections are in sync when using CQRS and EventSourcing?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm starting a new application and I want to use cqrs and eventsourcing. I got the idea of replaying events to recreate aggregates and snapshotting to speedup if needed, using in memory models, caching, etc.

My question is regarding large read models I don't want to hold in memory. Suppose I have an application where I sell products, and I want to listen to a stream of events like "ProductRegistered" "ProductSold" and build a table in a relational database that will be used for reporting or integration with another system. Suppose there are lots of records and this table may take from a few seconds to minutes to truncate/rebuild, and the application exports dozens of these projections for multiple purposes.

How does one handle the consistency of the projections in this scenario?

With in-memory data, it's quite simple and fast to replay the events. But I feel that external projections that are kept in disk will be much slower to rebuild.

1. Should I always start my application with a TRUNCATE TABLE + rebuild for every external projection? This seems impractical to me over time, but I may be worried about a problem I didn't have yet.
2. Since the table is itself like a snapshot, I could keep a "control table" to tell which event was the last one I handled for that projection, so I can replay only what's needed. But I'm worried about inconsistencies if the application or database crashes. It seems that checking the consistency of the table and rebuilding would be the same, which points to the solution 1 again.

How would you handle that in a way that is maintainable over time? Are there better solutions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The read model should be (in most cases) stored in a database and not stay in memory. If you are afraid getting out of sync because of an application crush then you should think about MSMQ for event bus.

Comment: That doesn't really solve anything, even with a message queue there are cases when the projection can go out of sync. The problem isn't the transport.

Comment: Ok, if the read model is out of sync I replay all events to the read model. And that will take its time depending on the hardware, database, etc. You can minimize this "out of sync" with a **transactional** MQ, because this will only happen, when the crash comes after event store is written and before the events are send to the MQ. And this is just a very small time gap.

Comment: And as you see it is about how you manage the transport of events from event store to projection ;o)

Comment: Ok, I get now what you're saying. If the queue is transactional, I would confirm the message receipt only after writing to the projection table. That solves the delivery guarantee and you don't have to truncate the table on app restart to ensure consistency.  For any other issue,  you'd rebuild not caring how much time it would take, as it would happen very occasionally. Is that it? You should probably write something as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Are you trying to find a way to make your projections [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) in the infrastructure? I think its hard to find a good way to do that since projections can handle the messages in many different ways. It is in my experience easier to handle this in each projection when needed.

Answer (score 6):

One way to handle this is the concept of checkpointing.  Essentially either your event stream or your whole system has a version number (checkpoint) that increments with each event.

For each projection, you store the last committed checkpoint that was applied.  At startup, you pull events greater than the last checkpoint number that was applied to the projection, and continue building your projection from there.  If you need to rebuild your projection, you delete the data AND the checkpoint and rerun the whole stream (or set of streams).

Caution: the last applied checkpoint and the projection's read models need to be persisted in a single transaction to ensure they do not get out of sync.

Comment: Thanks! That is similar to what I got from looking into NEventStore sources. It seems this is enough to guarantee ordering for projections in a single server. I was wondering how to do that in a multi-server setup, but maybe a master + standby is more than enough for an event store.

Comment: Assuming we have one incremental version by event stream, what if our projection listen events coming from more than one stream? Should we keep the current version for each event stream we listen to? If so, what if our projection doesn't listen to every event of these streams then we can't keep track of the version properly?

Comment: @MaximeGélinas Having a global checkpoint instead of (or in addition to) a per-stream version would solve these problems.  Other possible solutions would be too much for a comment.

Comment: @PhilSandler I created a new question about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56150852/5960632. It would be very appreciate if you can answer it!