# CQRS,ES: How to know if we have to reorder/ignore events on read side?

Tags: events, event-handling, cqrs, event-sourcing

Me and my team currently work on the read side of a CQRS and event-sourcing system.
We want our projectors to be able to listen to only a subset of all events and we want our projectors to be idempotent since an event can be published many times.
Here is our current architecture: 
[image: current architecture]

Since a projectionist doesn't handle all events how it can know if an event hasn't been received in the correct order or if an event has already been received? We can't use the sequence number because the sequence number is related to a stream and not an event type.

The terms "projectionist", "projection ledger" and "projector" comes from [this article](https://dev.to/barryosull/projection-building-blocks-what-youll-need-to-build-projections--5g1n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to know if we have to reorder/ignore events on read side?

The "Bus" is not the authority for order of events - that responsibility lies with the event store.  So a projectionist that needs to know what order things happen should query the store, rather than trying to reconstruct the original ordering from the information on the bus.

Greg Young's 2014 talk [Polyglot Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv2dKtPq0ME&t=24m55s) includes a good discussion of this point.

(The projectionist might query the event store via some API, rather than talking to the store directly - a curated atom feed based on the data in the store).

Comment: Indeed.  Knowing you have the correct, up-to-date, correctly ordered data as you project is critical.  I would add that without a global sequence, your projectionist will be much more complex, and will have to checkpoint per stream to handle idempotency.  It will also (likely) need to approximate a global sequence, possibly via a date or some other mechanism to avoid having to query and reprocess the whole stream constantly (and check whether EACH event has already been processed).

Answer (score 0):

Like proposed by @VoiceOfUnreason, we fixed the problem by ditching the bus and by replacing it with the change feed processor of CosmosDB since our events are stored in CosmosDB. We had no problem with this solution so far. The change feed processor is capable of managing the checkpoints and broadcasting the events to every projectors out of the box!